# Eigen::placeholders::all for Eigen array/matrix with pybind11

Tags: indexing, eigen, pybind11

I am building a c++ program linked to python code, using pybind11.
I use Eigen for the matrix operations.
I am having issues with the slicing of an Eigen array.
According to [Eigen documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSlicingIndexing.html), it is possible to slice an array using `Eigen::placeholders::all` -

```
std::vector<int> ind{4,2,5,5,3};
MatrixXi A = MatrixXi::Random(4,6);
cout << "Initial matrix A:\n" << A << "\n\n";
cout << "A(all,ind):\n" << A(Eigen::placeholders::all,ind) << "\n\n";
```

However, when I try to use this syntax in my code, I get the following error:

`error: ‘Eigen::indexing’ has not been declared`

I found an explanation for this - The Eigen header I used is of pybind11, not the original `Eigen` header.
This explains the issue, but not helping with a solution.

I tried including the original Eigen headers, but it won't include the `indexing` or `placeholders` namespaces.

Thank for your assistance!

edit:
Here is the code I tried to compile:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/eigen.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>
#include <pybind11/iostream.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>
#include <Eigen/Core>


namespace py = pybind11;



void example()
{
    std::vector<int> ind{4,2,5,5,3};
    Eigen::MatrixXi A = Eigen::MatrixXi::Random(4,6);
    std::cout << "Initial matrix A:\n" << A << "\n\n";
    std::cout << "A(all,ind):\n" << A(Eigen::placeholders::all,ind) << "\n\n";
}
```

For which I got the following error:

```
error: ‘Eigen::placeholders’ has not been declared
```

Comment: You *really* need to provide a minimum reproducible example for this, especially includes and stuff. Also, it seems like you use a lot of ```using namespace x``` which is generally discouraged. I'm not surprised you run into namespace issues with that coding style

Comment: Hi @Homer512, thanks for your reply. I added a code example to the original file.
I am not using "using ..." at all. 
Hope that helps clear the issue more.

Comment: That code works for me. Eigen-3.4.0 + pybind-2.10.0. Except I get a deprecation warning for ```Eigen::placeholders::all```. It is now simply ```Eigen::all```

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I was able to solve the issue - it was an issue with the cmake files, and specifically, the `FindEigen3.cmake` was missing under the cmake folder.
Somehow, (probably because of `pybind11/Eigen` header) the program was able to compile, but could not find all the relevant headers.
After adding the `FindEigen3.cmake` under the cmake folder, all included folders were correct, and I could use `Eigen::placeholders::all`.
Thanks @Homer512 for the assistance!